# Counting upstream features based on flow direction line segments?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, hydrology, arc-hydro

I am trying to find a way of counting how many lakes are upstream for each lake in my watershed. I feel as though I have the layers to accomplish this but am unsure of the tools/workflow. I have stream features, waterbody features, flow direction line features that show how the water flows from one lake to another. I also have a pour point feature for each of my lakes of interest that are snapped to the flow direction line segments.

Can you provide me with some direction on possible workflows?

[image: Pour points for each lake along flow direction line features.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your stream lines and pour points as inputs into a [geometric network](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geometric-networks/what-are-geometric-networks-.htm).  Then iterate through your pour points and use the trace upstream network to select all upstream lines from that point.  Select those lakes that intersect the selected lines.

Comment: Thanks! I used Trace Network as I'm on ArcGIS Pro but other then that difference this method worked.

Comment: Excellent, feel free to mark the answer as accepted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach for users who do not have the license to create Trace networks is to use [RivEX for ArcPro](https://www.rivex.co.uk/).

It has the tool [Find all upstream sites](https://www.rivex.co.uk/RivEX-Manual/Findallupstreamsites.html) which returns a table listing which sites are upstream of the sites in the layer to search. As well as returning who is upstream it also returns the distance. It's also capable of constraining the search to a subset of points by you building a simple expression (e.g. you could for example ask RivEX to find all upstream sites that were surveyed in 2024 and have a species abundance of *X*).